# Biogas temperature

Tags: gas-laws

What would be the temperature of Biogas when it is delivered to a boiler through a pipeline by a gas blower. Inlet pressure at gas blower is zero and at delivery it is 3.0 psi.

Comment: Initial temperature of Biogas is 40 degree C

Comment: What is the gas  mass flow rate and the amount of power being supplied by the blower?

Answer (score 2):

The compression by the blower can be used as an example of adiabatic compression.
$$pV^\gamma=\text{constant}$$
or
$$p_1V_1^\gamma=p_2V_2^\gamma$$
where $\gamma$ is the ratio of the heat capacities $\gamma=C_p/C_V=C_{\mathrm m,p}/C_{\mathrm m,V}=c_p/c_V$. You need to find a value of $\gamma$ suitable for your biogas, which is probably mainly a mixture of $\ce{CH4}$ and $\ce{CO2}$.

According to the ideal gas law,
$$p_1V_1=nRT_1$$
and
$$p_2V_2=nRT_2$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}p_1\left(\frac{nRT_1}{p_1}\right)^\gamma&=p_2\left(\frac{nRT_2}{p_2}\right)^\gamma\\[6pt]
p_1^{1-\gamma}T_1^\gamma&=p_2^{1-\gamma}T_2^\gamma\\[6pt]
\frac{T_1}{T_2}&=\left(\frac{p_1}{p_2}^{\frac{1-\gamma}{\gamma}}\right)\end{align}$$

The given initial temperature of $40\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ needs to be converted to the corresponding thermodynamic temperature $T_1=313.15\ \mathrm K$.

Note that, unfortunately, the given pressures are actually gauge pressures (also note that the use of the unit $\mathrm{psi}$ is deprecated). Assuming an ambient pressure of about $1\ \mathrm{bar}=14.5\ \mathrm{psi}$, the corresponding pressures are $p_1=0\ \mathrm{psi}+14.5\ \mathrm{psi}=14.5\ \mathrm{psi}$ and $p_2=3.0\ \mathrm{psi}+14.5\ \mathrm{psi}=17.5\ \mathrm{psi}$.